What is the proper replacement for QuerySingle in Glassmapper V5
We are working on the Sitecore upgrade.
below code that is used in older Glassmapper
  public override IBase_Lead_Gen_Form GetLeadGenFormItem()
  {
      var RequestAQuoteItemQuery = "./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='" + Site_FolderConstants.TemplateIdString + "']/Data/Forms/*[@@templateid='" + Request_A_QuoteConstants.TemplateIdString + "']";
      return _context.SitecoreService.QuerySingle<IRequest_A_Quote>(RequestAQuoteItemQuery);
  }

what is the proper replacement for this.

You can use GetItemByQueryOptions to replace the QuerySingle as below.
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;

public override IBase_Lead_Gen_Form GetLeadGenFormItem()
{
  var RequestAQuoteItemQuery = "./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='" + Site_FolderConstants.TemplateIdString + "']/Data/Forms/*[@@templateid='" + Request_A_QuoteConstants.TemplateIdString + "']";

  GetItemByQueryOptions builder = new GetItemByQueryOptions();
  builder.Query = new Query(RequestAQuoteItemQuery);
  builder.RelativeItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

  return _context.SitecoreService.GetItem<IRequest_A_Quote>(builder);
}

Inisde the RelativeItem, you will need to set the item against which the query should run.
Hope this helps!!! Let me  know in case you face any issues.

builder.RelativeItem = Sitecore.Context.Item; all the time this Sitecore.Context.item or different item we need to set?

@Rameshkumar it need to be set to the item against which the query should run. in your case ancestor query  needs to be fetched from which item, that needs to be set in RelativeItem. Hope this makes sense!!!
